# Assessing and reducing EMI from PWM LED lighting

Tags: emissions

I need to run 50 individually dimmable LED fixtures on a pair of wires 30m long. Total load will be about 6A at 48V DC. I have to get power and control down a single pair, and AFAIK there are basically two options:

1. Add an encoded high frequency carrier to the DC, as used in data over mains applications.
2. Use an H-bridge to supply power as square wave AC, and modulate it with PWM or FSK to encode the data.

I'm leaning towards option 2 as it will be cheaper, and also option 1 has the potential for lots of noise problems in the data with 50 PWM driven fixtures on the line.
Ideally I'd be sending data at 25kbit/s, but I think I could get away with 2.5kbit/s.

I don't need to pass any approvals, but I don't want to be causing problems with radiated interference. I don't know where to start when it comes to estimating or measuring the interference this setup will cause. Is a 30m cable carrying 6A switched at 2.5kHz (or 25kHz) a complete non starter?

Comment: How are you setting brightness and are all LEDs powered close to the end of the 30m cables?

Comment: The LEDs are fixtures spaced evenly along the cable run. Each fixture will have a microcontroller that decodes the data and drives the LEDs constant current with PWM. Each fixture needs to be individually addressable.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be able to use the "data-over-mains" solutions that are designed for AC power lines, but there are a lot of DC powerline communications products available, too. If you poke around enough, I bet that you will find a match for your application.

Here are some examples, although neither quite explicitly says that it supports 48V.

FROM TI: http://www.ti.com/tool/24VDCPLCEVM

FROM CYPRESS: http://www.cypress.com/?id=2330&rID=39248

"The CY8CPLCXX enables control of Automotive LED strobe, beacon, tail lights and indicators over the existing Direct Current (DC) 12V-42V Battery Powerline."

There are lots of others. I would probably advise against spinning your own option 1 based solution, unless you are a really confident analog designer. I would advise against an option 2 based solution, for both EMI and SI concerns.

Answer (score 0):

First off, 2.5kbits/s != 2.5kHz on the line.  That will be one of the frequencies, but the rise time of your square wave will tell you how many more harmonics exist and their relative power.

I would be looking at a protocol that is actually made to send data over a distance, and hopefully one that is differential over twisted pair to reduce noise issues.

Since this is send only, my first thought is of rs-422.  There are chips that do the rs-232 to rs-422 (or rs-485) translation.  It would require a small micro on each side, but worth it for not radiating a varying cornucopia of RF for lighting.  I have one Maxim part that does the rs-232 to rs-485, that I designed into a short run product.  I'll try to find that and update this answer.

Edit: OK, I missed the pair of wires bit.  There is no way I would run primary power reversing current of anything above a few hundred Hz in sine wave format through 30m of cable, without some serious EMI characterization and testing.  I would provide DC that I am modulating at the other end.

I'm a bigger fan of your #1 option..  Have a sine wave oscillator, whose operating frequency is dependent on how much data you need to send and how fast.  Then inject this fairly low voltage signal on to the higher voltage DC line as digital encoded PWM carrier.  All that is required at the LED is AC coupled low pass filter to get the data out.  This is slightly more complex, but drastically reduces EMI.

If you use a know data rate, something like full pulse for 1 and short pulse for 0 is common with IR remotes.  Actually, this shares much of the same issues with an IR remote.  The IR detector sees ambient light (like the large DC power voltage) and it sees the small 40 kHz carrier modulation.  By AC coupling, then LP filtering, you get the envelope of the PWM.  Very few components, to drive this directly into a digital input.

Also keep in mind that your voltage along the cable is going to drop.  So if equal brightness is a desire, you will need to adjust your drive to compensate for this.  The higher your source DC voltage, the lower this becomes a factor.

Edit #2: Why your second option is a bad idea

The frequency spectrum is based on frequency of the periodic signal and the rise time.  This is modeled as a clock pulse, not actual data, for simplicity.  Period variation controls the placement of frequency spectrum, but rise time controls the knee location.  The frequency components are considered significant up until \$1/(\pi t_r)\$, the frequency based on rise time (\$t_r\$) of the trapezoidal pulse.  If you have the pulse rising relatively slow, you only get a few harmonics that are important.  However, it is never a bit rate = frequency, for a trapezoidal data signal.

[image: http://www.learnemc.com/tutorials/Time-Frequency/Time-Frequency_images/TextFig23-9.png]

Fairly good article on this where I found this picture: [Learn EMC Time Frequency Notes](http://www.learnemc.com/tutorials/Time-Frequency/Time_Frequency_Notes.html)

Comment: His issue is that he is trying to combine power and data over the same wires.

Comment: Exactly W5VO, thanks. If I could run a twisted pair too it would be trivial!

Comment: It's a fairly sweeping statement to make that 2.5kbps = 2.5kHz on the line - 2.5kHz will be there statistically (because of the randomness of data) but it won't be there if the data is assumed to be a square-wave.

Comment: In one second I'll be reversing the current 2500 times. I'm just looking for a rough idea as to whether this is feasible without causing major interference.

Comment: If you use square wave, absolutely NO.  If you use sine waves, MAYBE.

Comment: @Andy aka - I don't know if that is to me or to user40479.  I explicitly state that 2.5 kbits/s is NOT equal to 2.5 kHz.  Far from it with a trapezoidal wave data signal.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So, option 2 is a non-starter in your opinion then. I'm fine with dealing with the voltage drop and implementing data protocols, I just didn't know how to assess the interference issues.

Comment: Make your PWM frequency sufficiently different from your data carrier frequency, to minimize interference issues with data stream.  The slower you can send your data, the easier it is going to be.  You best bet may be to use a band pass filter before the envelope detector, to filter out both the PWM and DC energy.

Comment: That's a good website, nice clear explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd send DC power down the line and use radio for controlling the LEDs. A 30m cable can only mean a maximum of 30m between transmitter and receiver. There are plenty of options out there. Data rate requirements are nowhere near tortuous either. I'd consider the [nRF24L01](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01P) from Nordic or TI's [CC2500](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=cc2500&fileType=pdf).

There will be minimum EMI using this method compared to switching it and shipping it down the line.

Comment: I did consider this, but I'd really struggle to get the receiver into the space available, and it'll be a lot more expensive.

Comment: Have you seen how small they are and how cheap they are. Is "size" and "cost" that critical?

Comment: Yes, but it's not just the chip, there's the other parts and the cost of design. I have a strip of PCB 6mm wide to fit it on, and it's shared with a PWM driver and in an aluminium case. I'm not an RF engineer, but this doesn't sound easy to me.